# Plot two graphs on different levels on y axis (primary and secondary) using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hi I want to create a plot similar to below,
Basically, the data on x axis is continous, and data on primary y axis ia a factor (0,1).
On secondary y axis it freq or counts on data points in each bin on x axis

How can I plot something similar to this in ggplot?
This is my data frame example:

```
head(data2)
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  x_bin        Death_prob   Val   
  <fct>                  <int> <int> 
1 (0.668,2.39]               0    49    
2 (0.668,2.39]               1     3    
3 (2.39,4.11]                0    92   
4 (2.39,4.11]                1     8   
5 (4.11,5.84]                0    27   
6 (4.11,5.84]                1     8
```

Original data looks something like this:

```
   > head(df)
  X  Sample     Death_prob  DNA_concentr    x_bin
 1 12906               1       1.599731         (0.668,2.39] 
 2 12907               0       1.711472            (0.668,2.39] 
 3 12910               0       1.861115            (0.668,2.39] 
 4 12911               1       4.749104           (4.11,5.84] 
5 12913               0       1.633699            (0.668,2.39] 
6 12918               0       4.003156           (2.39,4.11]
```

the graph is showing DNA concentration on x axis (in percentage, and it is binned), and probability of death (0=alive, 1=Dead) on primary y axis, and the number of measured data points in each bin is indicated by the blue bar graphs (right Y axis). it is a beautiful graph to show lots of info in one plot. I am able to plot the data on x axis and primary y axis, but I am unable to plot the blue graphs separately for level 0 and 1 on secondary y axis.

Example plot is here:

[image: TWOBAR]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this makes for a pretty confusing plot, and I'm not convinced about it from a data visualization perspective, but then, I'm not quite sure what the plot is supposed to show.

It's not possible to have a bar chart in ggplot with both upgoing and downgoing bars coming from different baselines, so you will probably have to draw your own rectangles here using a bit of data manipulation:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(x_bin = as.character(x_bin),
         left = as.numeric(gsub('^\\(|,.*$', '', x_bin)),
         right = as.numeric(gsub('^.*,|\\]', '', x_bin)),
         upper = ifelse(Death_prob == 0, Val / 150, 1),
         lower = ifelse(Death_prob == 0, 0, 1 - Val / 150)) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = left, xmax = right, ymin = lower, ymax = upper,
                fill = ifelse(Death_prob == 0, 'A', 'B')),
            color = 'black', alpha = 0.5) +
  scale_y_continuous("Death probability 1", labels = ~ .x * 150, 
                     breaks = seq(0, 1, len = 7),
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~ (1 - .x) * 150, 
                     name = 'Death probability 0')) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('red4', 'blue4'), guide = 'none') +
  coord_cartesian(expand = FALSE) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.line.y.left = element_line(color = 'red4'),
        axis.line.y.right = element_line(color = 'blue4'),
        axis.text.y.left = element_text(color = 'red4'),
        axis.text.y.right = element_text(color = 'blue4'),
        axis.title.y.left = element_text(color = 'red4'),
        axis.title.y.right = element_text(color = 'blue4'))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Alan for quick response, the graph is showing DNA concentration on x axis (in percentage, and it is binned), and probability of death (0=alive, 1=Dead) on primary y axis, and the number of measured data points in each bin is indicated by the blue bar graphs (right Y axis). it is a beautiful graph to show lots of info in one plot. I am able to plot the data on x axis and primary y axis, but I am unable to plot the blue graphs separately for level 0 and 1 on secondary y axis. I think now it is more clear.